# AWS DynamoDB Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to add custom metadata on DynamoDB when performing such operations as PutItem, Query, Scan, GetItem, etc.? Where I can add and read those metadata?

Example:

```
"sample-key": "sample-value"
```

I think the **S3** has the `Metadata` field on its `UploadInput`. While the **SQS** has the `MessageSystemAttributeValue`.

Comment: What would be the purpose of adding custom metadata to a table query or scan operation? What is your underlying requirement?

Comment: It will be used for the tracing where it will be passed across the services.

Comment: Read up on [AWS X-Ray](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/) for application observability.

Comment: I have used OpenTelemetry for observability but seems not to be working. It has a lambda layer that will collect the traces and will push them to the remote collector. But they're both in the same region. Do you think that there is something wrong with the setup?

Comment: Example [here](https://seed.run/blog/how-to-trace-serverless-apps-with-aws-x-ray.html) of x-ray instrumentation of a Lambda function making calls to DynamoDB and SNS that might generate some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue I'm facing right now is the traces are being generated by the lambda function and not by the lambda layer because both the lambda layer collector and remote collector are sitting in the same account and region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in DynamoDB like how you do it in S3 or SQS.

For DynamoDB, you simply need to add an attribute to the item when you put/update it, in this case I call the attribute `metadata`:

```
  Item={
            'pk': 'jose.schneller@somewhere.com',
            'sk': 'engineer',
            'username': 'joses',
            'first_name': 'Jose',
            'last_name': 'Schneller',
            'name': 'Jose Schneller',
            'age': 27,
            'address': {
                'road': '12341 Fish Rd',
                'city': 'Freeland',
                'pcode': 98249,
                'state': 'WA',
                'country': 'USA'
            }, 
            'metadata':{
                'sample-key': 'sample-value'
            }
}
```

This means you get the items metadata each time you read the item.

Comment: Oh, okay. Been looking for a way about this the whole day to make it possible since I'm a noob. Thanks for this. :)

Comment: No such thing as a silly question. Keep getting after it 

Comment: Now that we know the OP's underlying requirement (observability), this seems to be answering a different question. This would not allow the system to trace a request across various services because the metadata would have to be transient and flow with the requests, not be persisted in a DynamoDB item.

Comment: If you read the first line in my answer I clearly state that it's not possible in DynamoDB. I merely suggested a workaround and tried to be helpful.

Comment: This answer is really helpful to me to know that it is not possible in DynamoDB and gave me a piece of new knowledge about the service since I'm a noob and trying to figure things out :)